# HighCharts: wrong data shown on datetime xaxis

Tags: datetime, highcharts, axis

I have a wrong point data shown.
It doesn't show the correct data, check out the picture.

Startpoint is Date.UTC(2016, 06, 30) and not the Date.UTC(2016, 07, 30) as in the tooltip. Here is the result I get:

[image]

```
$(function() {
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'spline'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Waterflow'
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        day: '%e'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Date'
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Flow im Mio'
      },
      min: 0
    },
    tooltip: {
      headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
      pointFormat: '{point.x:%e. %b}: {point.y:.2f} m'
    },
    plotOptions: {
      spline: {
        marker: {
          enabled: true
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Main',
      data: ([
        [Date.UTC(2016, 06, 30), 3072.541365],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 07, 31), 3315.618228],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 08, 31), 3367.458135],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 09, 30), 3370.195785],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 10, 31), 3424.501986],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 11, 30), 3479.865412],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 12, 31), 3521.730275],
      ])
    }, ]
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Date.UTC(Year,Month*,Day,Hour,Minute,Seconds)` the **Month** is starting from **0**. This is mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC).

So to specify the month `June` you have to use **`5`** and not *`6`*.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for that I read this many times but not recognizes the '0'